# Django - Handling several file upload requests at a time?

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, uwsgi

I am developing a django application which handles lots of file uploads from multiple clients periodically. Each file is around 1 to 10 megabytes.

Since uploads are thread blocking I can only serve a number of requests equivalent to the number of uwsgi workers/processes (4 in my case).

What should I do to increase throughput?

Is it advisable to increase number of processes/workers in uwsgi?
 
What should be the upper limit?
 
Is there any other solution that I can use in this scenario?

Stack: django+uwsgi+nginx running on amazon ec2 and s3 buckets used for storing zip files.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use asynchronous task queue to upload multiple files at a time.
These tasks can execute asynchronously (in the background)

I am using Celery/Disque to acheive the same .

Read about disque [here](https://github.com/antirez/disque)

You can do it via

```
pip install django-queued-storage
```

For more refer [here](https://github.com/jazzband/django-queued-storage)

Answer (score 0):

> What should be the upper limit?

That depends on your hardware such as quantity of core in your server

> Is there any other solution that I can use in this scenario?

Consider using Celery/rabbitMQ. Celery could be used to process asynchronously file or upload to S3 and notify the events to rabbitMQ